# Drupal gives `Notice: Undefined index: highlighted in include ..` error during theme creation

Tags: theming

So, I have a fresh instal of Drupal 7.34 and decide to create a simple theme.

I created a folder in `/sites/all/themes/samayo` and in it, I placed a `screenshot.png, style.css, samayo.info` inside `samayo.info` I pasted these settings.

```
name = samayo
description = samayo theme
version = 0.2.1
core = 7.x
engine = phptemplate

screenshot = screenshot.png

regions[left] = Left sidebar
regions[right] = Right sidebar
regions[content] = Content
regions[header] = Header
regions[footer] = Footer
regions[footer_content_1] = Footer Content 1
regions[footer_content_2] = Footer Content 2
regions[footer_content_3] = Footer Content 3

stylesheets[all][] = style.css
```

Went to drupa and chose this them as default, and I am getting this error for the past 2 hours.

```
Notice: Undefined index: highlighted in include() (line 126 of /var/www/public/dev.samayo/modules/system/page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: sidebar_first in include() (line 138 of /var/www/public/dev.samayo/modules/system/page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: sidebar_second in include() (line 144 of /var/www/public/dev.samayo/modules/system/page.tpl.php).
Warning: include_once(/var/www/public/dev.samayo): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in _drupal_theme_initialize() (line 209 of /var/www/public/dev.samayo/includes/theme.inc).
Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/var/www/public/dev.samayo/' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in _drupal_theme_initialize() (line 209 of /var/www/public/dev.samayo/includes/theme.inc).
```

All the answer I checked do not seem to affect anything, including [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2028847#comment-10002265) which suggested placing

```
regions[highlighted] = Highlighted
```

in the `samayo.info` file, but even this could not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

this is probably stemming from the default page.tpl.php which is expecting to find a region `highlighted`.  The best approach IMHO would be to create a custom page tpl that excludes the regions you don't use, and includes the regions you do.

You can find the default page.tpl.php under modules/system - just copy the file to your theme directory (or sub folder templates) make the changes you want, and then clear the cache

Comment: I am not at that level yet. I can't modify this. I am using a book and video guide to learn about creating themes, so I am stuck at the first part. Which Means, I may get to the point of editing templates later, but now .. it seems complex to just jump and change anything. But, just out of curiosity .. what regions should I exclude from my example to make this thing work.

Comment: No need to hurt you brain with my noob question. I removed all `regions` and it all works.

Comment: the default page.tpl.php contains `<?php if ($page['highlighted']): ?><div id="highlighted"><?php print render($page['highlighted']); ?></div><?php endif; ?>
` - this is looking for the highlighted index, which doesn't exist if its not defined in the info file. did you clear the cache after adding regions[highlighted] to the info file?  that should have picked it up and removed the error

Comment: Nope, like I said .. I removed everything from the info, exception the required ones.